# How to submit form by parent div

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

This is my first question on stackoverflow! I hope that I am explaining clearly what my question is.

My question is:
How can I submit a form with js by the parent div.

I know I can submit a form like this:

document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

But I don't want to select the form by it's own id but by the id of the parent div.

I want something like this:

```
<div id="demo">
<form>
<input type="text">
</form>
</div>

<script>
document. get form in div with id demo .submit();
</script>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#demo form').submit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('#demo form').submit();
```

I messed up. Thanks to the comments.

Comment: It is `form` and not `input`. Also it is `querySelector()` and not `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonas! Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="demo" style="background: #ddd; padding: 50px;">
<form id="form">
<input type="text">
</form>
</div>

<script>
var parent = document.getElementById("demo"),
    form = document.getElementById("form");
  
parent.addEventListener("click", function(){
  form.submit();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors and ***querySelector*** method for access to DOM nodes:

```
document.querySelector('#demo form').submit();
```

Comment: @Dropout Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can take parent div and find all his children and pick needed

```
let test = document.querySelector('#demo')

test.children[0].submit()
```